# IO Отказано в доступе по пути

Tags: c#, io

Пишу прогу, для удаления пользователей компа. Сделал чистку реестра, осталось добавить возможность удаления папок по пути C:\Users, однако при попытке удаления через DirectoryInfo, получаю ошибку типа:

> System.IO.IOException: Отказано в доступе по пути "C:\Users\user1\3D Objects"

Код программы:

```
string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories("C:\\Users");
for (int i = 0; i < directories.Length; i++)
{
    new DirectoryInfo(directories[i]).Delete(recursive: true);
}
```

Comment: А вы руками удалить можете ту папку?

Comment: Программа запускается с правами администратора?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50346802/12888024

Answer (score 0):

я ресетал себе атрибуты:

```
directoryInfo.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
```

у тебя в коде это будет выглядеть вот так:

```
new DirectoryInfo(directories[i]){ Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal }
        .Delete(recursive: true);
```

Comment: Не помогает, пробовал.